# R: Implementing the iterated conditional modes technique

Tags: r, syntax

My problem is mainly a syntax problem, caused by my vague programming abilities.

I have implemented an energy function:

```
NRG <- function(y, x, h, beta, eta){
    y2 <- addmargins(y, FUN=function(y) 1)
    neigh <- matrix(nrow=nrow(y), ncol=ncol(y))
    for (i in 1:nrow(y)) {
        for (j in 1:ncol(y)) {
        neigh[i,j] <- sum(prod(y[i,j], y2[i-1, j]),+ prod(y[i,j], y2[i, j-1]) + 
            prod(y[i,j], y2[i+1, j]) + prod(y[i,j], y2[i, j+1]))
        }   
        }
    E <- h * sum(y) - beta * sum(neigh) - eta * sum(y*x)
    return(E)
}
```

I then want to use the ICM technique to find the configuration with the lowest energy.

My data=y I want to iterate over is a matrix of dimensions 300x300, with every value being either -1 or +1.
x is intially a copy of y.
My initial approach is to create a matrix as a copy owith every value multiplied by -1 = rv_y. Then I would iterate over every value of my data and replace every value in x with the value of rv_y if it gives a lower value in my fucntion NRG:

```
ICM <- function(y, x, h, beta, eta){
    rv_y <- y*-1
    for (i in 1:y){
        if (NRG(y, x, h, beta, eta) > NRG(rv_y, x, h, beta, eta)) {
            x[i] <- x[i*-1]
        }
    }
    return(x)
}
```

Am I on the right track or is my approach wrong?